# Meromorphic function on the Riemann surfaces

Tags: riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions

Let $V$ be a Riemann surface, $x\in V$, and $B:=B(x,r)$ some small ball (in a local chart). It is well known that there is a meromorphic function $f$ on $V$ with the only pole at $x$. What I’d like to ask of is if there is a meromorphic f on V that has a pole at x and additionally such that $|f|<1$ outside $B$?

Comment: Just multiply your function with a single pole on a sufficiently small number.

Comment: My question was actually if it is possible to find a meromorphic function is bounded on $V\setminus B$ (look at $z+ 1/z$ on the plane --- what you want does not for this particular one)

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the question is about compact Riemann surfaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For open surfaces, there are counterexamples. The first one was constructed by P. Myrberg:

Ueber die analytische Fortsetzung von beschrankten Funktionen, Ann. Acad. Sci. Fenn., Ser. A. I N:o 58 (1949)

Since this paper is difficult to obtain (and written in German), I refer to another paper

Heins, Maurice,
Riemann surfaces of infinite genus.
Ann. of Math. (2) 55 (1952), 296–317,

Which proves an even stronger result: there is an open Riemann surface, such that if you remove a disk from it, then on the remaining surface every non-constant meromorphic function takes all complex values, except at most two of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!
Can I have one more question? I took a quick look at the paper and it seems that the surface constructed there is parabolic. Can I ask about the answer within the class of hyperbolic Riemann surfaces?

Comment: It is parabolic (before you remove the disk) in the sense that there is no Green function. So your new question is: suppose that a surface has a Green function. Does there exist a function with a single pole which is bounded outside a neighborhood of this pole? I suppose that the answer is still negative but do not have a ready example.